# calculate percentage increase and decrease of two values

Tags: asp-classic

I take This Week's Revenue and Last Week's Revenue values from the server and save them as:
RevenueThisWeek = objRevenueThisWeek("REVENUE")
RevenueLastWeek = objRevenueLastWeek("REVENUE")
Then, I calculate percentage of them as:
RevenuePercent = RevenueThisWeek - RevenueLastWeek
RevenuePercent = RevenuePercent / RevenueLastWeek
RevenuePercent = RevenuePercent * 100

Problem here is, if both  RevenueThisWeek and RevenueLastWeek are 0, I receive the following error message.

Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a0006'

Overflow

---

### edit

Forgot to mention. I created an if statement as

```
If (RevenueThisWeek AND RevenueLastWeek) = "0" Then
Else
RevenuePercent = RevenueThisWeek - RevenueLastWeek
RevenuePercent = RevenuePercent / RevenueLastWeek
RevenuePercent = RevenuePercent * 100   
End If
```

But this gave me results like:

```
            Last Week   This Week   % Change 
Revenue  $49.99       $72.97       0%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RevenuePercent = RevenueThisWeek - RevenueLastWeek
If RevenueLastWeek >= .01 Then '1 cent minimum. >0 can get messy.'
   RevenuePercent = RevenuePercent / RevenueLastWeek
Else
   RevenuePercent = 0
End If
RevenuePercent = RevenuePercent * 100
```

**Why the >.01?**

VBScript doesn't have a decimal type and defaults to floats which means you could end up with a value of .0000004505 or something ugly which will still result in an overflow. If you deal with tenths of a cent change it to

```
If RevenueLastWeek >= .001 Then
```

Answer (score 3):

[Divide by Zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are asking ASP to perform the following calculation:

```
RevenuePercent = RevenueThisWeek - RevenueLastWeek
RevenuePercent = RevenuePercent / RevenueLastWeek
RevenuePercent = RevenuePercent * 100
```

or, given the figure of 0 for RevenueThisWeek and RevenueLastWeek :

```
RevenuePercent = 0 - 0
RevenuePercent = 0/0
RevenuePercent = 0*100
```

the problematic line is actually the middle calculation:

**RevenuePercent = 0/0**

as you are asking a computer to divide by 0 - and that's not possible. You'll need to add an IF statement along the lines of the following pseudocode:

```
IF RevenueLastWeek>0 THEN ...perform calculation.. ELSE RevenuePercent=0 ENDIF
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially this is what you are doing:

RevenuePercent = (objRevenueThisWeek("REVENUE") - objRevenueLastWeek("REVENUE"))*100/objRevenueLastWeek("REVENUE")

If objRevenueLastWeek("REVENUE") = 0 then you are dividing by 0 and hence
the overflow. You may need a conditional to account for this case.

--